# Showing set is measurable in a product space w.r.t. the product $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Statement:** Let $(X,\mathcal{B}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is $\mathcal{B}$-measurable. Together with $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}[\mathbb{R}], m)$, the set 
$$\{(x,t)\in X\times \mathbb{R} : 0\leq t\leq f(x)\}$$
is measurable in $\mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{B}[\mathbb{R}]$.

**My attempt:** 
When $f$ is a simple function $\chi_S$, the set
$$\{(x,t)\in X\times \mathbb{R} : 0\leq t\leq \chi_S(x)\} = S \times [0,1],$$ thus in $\mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{B}[\mathbb{R}]$.

When $f$ is the sum of two simple functions $\chi_S + \chi_K$, the set is 
$$ (S\cap K)\times [0,2] \;\bigcup\; S/(S\cap K)\times [0,1] \;\bigcup \; K/(S\cap K)\times [0,1] ,$$
which is in $\mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{B}[\mathbb{R}]$.

Using the above fact, we know for any simple function $f$, the set 
$$\{(x,t)\in X\times \mathbb{R} : 0\leq t\leq f(x)\} \in \mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{B}[\mathbb{R}].$$

Using the fact that for any unsigned $\mathcal{B}$ measurable function, there exists a sequences of monotone increasing simple functions $f_n$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1(X,\mu)$, and there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ such that $f_{n_k} \rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e.
$${\{(x,t)\in X\times \mathbb{R} : 0\leq t\leq f(x)\} } = \bigcup_k {\{(x,t)\in X\times \mathbb{R} : 0\leq t\leq f_{n_k}(x)\} },$$
outside of a $\mu\times m$ null set. 
thus ${\{(x,t)\in X\times \mathbb{R} : 0\leq t\leq f(x)\} } $ is in $\mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{B}[\mathbb{R}]$.

Is my proof correct? and is there any other way to argue for this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct, but some points should be adjusted. For example, the ``pointwise a.e." is not necessary, because in fact you can find an increasing sequence of simple functions converging *everywhere* to $f$.

Here is a perhaps shorter proof. Note that you have $t\leq f(x)$ if and only if $t\leq r$ for every rational number $r>f(x)$. So, if you call your set $A$, the following equivalence holds true for any $(x,t)\in X\times\mathbb R$:
$$(x,t)\in A\iff t\geq 0\;{\rm and}\; \forall r\in\mathbb Q\;:\left(f(x)\geq r\;{\rm or}\; t\leq r \right) $$
If you call $B_r$ the $\{ (x,t);\; f(x)\geq r\}$, this means that
$$A=X\times [0,\infty[\, \cap\,\bigcap_{r\in\mathbb Q}\Bigl( B_r\cup (X\times (-\infty, r])\Bigr)  $$
So $A$ is in $\mathcal B\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ because all sets $B_r$ are.

Note that the *measure* has nothing to do in the story.